# check several lists with several for loops

Tags: python, list, loops

```
keylist = ['A/P', 'A/Q', 'B/P', 'B/Q', 'C/P', 'C/Q']
List = ['A','B','C']
```

I want to make an Operation for every element in `List` and for every element in `keylist` :

```
for n in List:
    for key in keylist:
        if key.split('/')[0] == List[n] and key.split('/')[-1] == 'P':
            try:
                print(n) #placeholder
            except:
                pass
```

Basically, I want to check if the first split element of `keylist` is an element of `List` but the Output is an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: use `if key.split('/')[0] == n` instead of `if key.split('/')[0] == List[n]`.

Comment: well, that helped. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because n you are using in List[n] is not an index to element in List.

```
for n in List:    # here n is not the index to element in list but element itself. 
    for key in keylist: # so you can't use List[n] below e.g. n is 'A' in first iteration
        if key.split('/')[0] == List[n] and key.split('/')[-1] == 'P':
            try:
                print(n) #placeholder
            except:
                pass
```

If you need index of element in the list, use code as below.

```
for idx, ele in enumerate(List):
    for key in keylist:
        if key.split('/')[0] == List[idx] and key.split('/')[-1] == 'P':
            try:
                print(List[idx])  # or print(ele)
            except:
                pass
```

Here, `ele == List[idx]`

Answer (score 0):

```
keylist = ['A/P', 'A/Q', 'B/P', 'B/Q', 'C/P', 'C/Q']
List = ['A','B','C']

for n in List:
    for key in keylist:
        if ((key.split('/')[0] in List) and (key.split('/')[1] == 'P')):
            try:
                print(n) #placeholder
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

> Flat is better than nested

```
for key in keylist:
    s = key.split('/')
    if s[0] in List and s[-1] == 'P':
        try:
            print(s[0]) #placeholder
        except:
            pass
```

This will work as long as the elements in `List` are unique. Your algorithm will duplicate outputs for duplicates in `List`. This algorithm will not.